# Websphere single classloader equivalence in jboss

Tags: jboss, websphere, classloader

We've got a project migrating from websphere to jboss. In the websphere deployment document, there's a step specifying war class loader policy: single class loader for application. Just wondering, what's the jboss equivalence for this step?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Should check this out:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration

IIRC, JBoss already uses a unified class loader by default (well at least the last time I used it which was 2 years ago). You actually have to disable it in your configuration.